# What are current trends in autistic treatment regarding hyper sensitivity?

Tags: autism

What are current trends in autistic treatment regarding hyper sensitivity?

Comment: I am sorry to hear about your predicament. Unfortunately, this forum expressly prohibits medical advice. Perhaps you could consider rephrasing your question: something like "what are current trends in autistic treatment regarding hyper sensitivity?" may find a better reception.

Comment: Title Altered. Please Check.

Comment: Thank you: I've added a couple of more updates to remove the medical advice request. Note that answers to this question *may not* relate to your child. Also note that this question may remain closed due to being "unresearched". I recommend taking 10 minutes, [Googling the issues](https://www.google.com/search?q=autistic+hypersensitivity+treatment&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS592US592&oq=autistic+hypersensitivity+treatment&aqs=chrome..69i57.8896j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and including some of the results (and discussing why they aren't good enough for you)...

Comment: ...  [This one](http://autism.wikia.com/wiki/Sensory_issues), for instance, discusses some home treatment options that seem to make sense. To show initial research, you should briefly summarize this article (and any others you find in your search) and discuss why they aren't good enough to answer this current question.

Comment: Due to the great diversity that is presented in autism, also in relation to sensitivity, it is not easy to offer a response, nor by the large professional organizations that consider in many cases an evaluation before something else. Perhaps Sensory integrative therapy, although of course therapies that work the sensory from another approach (based on behavior, based on language, based on activities) can be extremely effective.